# Moviepy: no audio in written video on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, moviepy

I'm trying to resize videos using **moviepy**. It runs totally fine when running on local, but on AWS BeanStalk, there is no audio in the rendered video.

```
clip_resized = clip.resize(height=video_max_height)
clip_resized.write_videofile(RESIZED_VIDEO_NAME, temp_audiofile="temp-audio.m4a",
                                     remove_temp=True,
                                     codec="libx264",
                                     audio_codec="aac", fps=30,
                                     logger=None, threads=4)
```

I'm using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858105/11889259) to install ffmpeg on AWS

Similar question for [heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54979858/11889259)